# Is it possible to use RSAwithSHA1 in php?

Tags: java, php, rsa, digital-signature, sha1

Is it possible to use `"RSAwithSHA1"` as used for `Signature.getInstance("RSAwithSHA1")` in PHP?

I've generated the keys using:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 1024
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj i have a private key, for create signature and use in hava, php to java

Comment: SHA1withRSA (**not** RSAwithSHA1, first the hash is calculated, then the RSA modular exponentiation is used) indicates the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding scheme for signature generation using a SHA-1 message digest / secure hash. PHP also implements this scheme. You can see how in the duplicate.